# How to change time zone of Parse.com？

Tags: timezone

Is there a way to change the time zone in Parse? The "updatedAt" column in the "Core" section got different time zone as mine.

[image: updatedAt column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-saving), the `updatedAt` field is provided by Parse and isn't available until you save the Object.  So you cannot change the value.

What you can do is make your own [Date](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-types) field for storing the date in your timezone. Every time `updatedAt` changes for a row, convert the new value to your timezone and save it in your Date field.

Comment: Oh, that is inconvenient...  Like Google Adsense, you can choose the time zone for your account and all your auto generated data will be within that time zone. However, in Parse account settings, no option like this.